How can I prevent the my Computer with Ubuntu to freeze because of 100% Ram usage?
I have a computer with
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
RAM:            33GB
RAM SWAP:       1GB
CPU             12 virtual cores (enough)
Now every other day my RAM usage spikes at 100% including swap and starts to freeze.
(CPU usage also spike during that time, shortly after RAM hitting 100%)
Usually, because some Browser uses like 20% of the RAM.
And yes I worked for a while now by simply closing the browser or killing its process when I notice the system lags.
But it starts to annoy me since I can't think of a time when I had this problem with Windows.
What I want is that I can work without some application using all RAM and the system freezing.
I also still want to use Ubuntu like a normal person and not start the browser in some weird way like cgroup-tools.
My best idea was to reserve resources for the system to run, and to kick programs (and browser tabs) out of the RAM if they weren't used for a while.
Is there a user-friendly way to achieve something like this? Because I don't think adding more RAM is solving the problem.
Also, I don't care if one application is unresponsive, as long as I can restart it.
I can handle difficult setups but after that, I don't want to think about how to start programs or do some terminal magic every day, where I need to remember precise commands.
EDIT:
Added a pictures and some info:


Little Background to those processes:
I am a web developer, meaning I constantly will have a browser open including devtools. This is what you see as Isolated Web Co.
node is for node.js
Don't know why slack is using that much ram but ok.
Anyways, I will have tons of applications open that I will need.
Usually Its Firefox, Chromium(sometimes), VS Code with extensions, Slack, webex, postman and a few other minor ones.
Not accounting applications I develop or things like remote kubernetes.
Sure we can argue for more RAM or better PC but my Issue is that I don't want freezes no matter what I do. I can handle an application that complains about not enough ram. But I don't accept having to kill my computer because the Browser is playing Monopoly with my RAM.
Output of cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
EDIT 2: Added Info about Browser
snap list | grep -E 'firefox|chromium'
chromium                   124.0.6367.118              2842   latest/stable    canonical**       -
chromium-ffmpeg            0.1                         37     latest/stable    canonical**       -
firefox                    125.0.2-1                   4173   latest/stable    mozilla**         -

dpkg -l | grep -E 'firefox|chromium'
ii  firefox                                    1:1snap1-0ubuntu2                       amd64        Transitional package - firefox -> firefox snap
ii  firefox-locale-en                          1:1snap1-0ubuntu2                       all          Transitional package - firefox-locale-en -> firefox snap


Just FYI, you never need to remember precise commands. Whenever something like that comes along, you just make an alias or a shell function instead. That said, what you describe is not normal. You have 32G of RAM (you said 33 but I assume that was a typo or the count included swap), which is way, way more than enough. Can you add the output of cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness to your question? Have you identified what program causes this? Could it just be a buggy tool with a memory leak?

short direct answer ... add more swap.  But realistically, give us more info on what is using 32GB of memory.  Virtualization is the only thing that has ever gotten me close to 32GB usage.

@rtaft I don't think it will fix the use and only delay it. The computer will just use up that swap and I am back to square one.

In Firefox currently 66 but it varies between 20-100. I use Chromium mainly in private mode with max 5 Tabs.

I just read your edit after posting my last comment. It makes more sense now. The default Firefox (and Chromium, I think) are Snap versions. Try switching from the snap to the deb versions of the browser.The snap versions run in sand-boxed environment and take up more resources. The deb versions may be more efficient for you.

Interesting. I will try that. But not sure if that fixes everything but lets see.

See this Q&A for switching Fierfox from snap to deb. and increase the swap size to 64GB while you are at it. Then you can see how much of the swap gets used and reduce it if you don't need that much. With some swap space, you will get more time to notice system slowdown before it the 100% memory full freeze and close tabs to avoid the crash.

Thanks a lot. I was about to do it with Copilot from github, and while it had a sensible approach, copilot admitted that your Q&A is more detailed and better.

See How to increase swap space?
